# Migrating to swift - Problem with completion Handlers

Tags: objective-c, swift, migration, objective-c-blocks

I'm trying to "translate" a method from Objective C because I'm doing better with swift but I'm getting one error I can't solve.

This is the method:

```
+(void) getFormObjectForWorkflowTypeId: (NSNumber *) workflowTypeId andEmployeeId: (NSNumber *) employeeId onCompletion: (void (^)(VOCForm *form)) completionHandler {

    VOCGetFormRC *configuration = [[VOCGetFormRC alloc] initWithWorkflowTypeId: workflowTypeId andEmployeeId: employeeId];
    VOCNetworkManager *networkManager = [VOCNetworkManager sharedManager];
    [networkManager startRequestWithConfiguration: configuration
                                        onSuccess:^(NSArray * _Nonnull jsonResponse) {

                                            BOOL responseState = [jsonResponse valueForKey:@"success"];

                                            if (responseState) {

                                                NSDictionary *formData = [[[jsonResponse valueForKey: @"data"] valueForKey: @"elements"] valueForKey: @"form"];

                                                NSError *error;
                                                VOCForm *form = [[VOCForm alloc] initWithDictionary: formData error: &error];

                                                if (error) {

                                                    [VOCLogUtils printLogForClass: self methodName: NSStringFromSelector(_cmd) andError: error];

                                                    if (completionHandler) {
                                                        completionHandler (nil);
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                else {

                                                    if (completionHandler) {
                                                        completionHandler (form);
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                            else {

                                                if (completionHandler) {
                                                    completionHandler(nil);
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                        onFailure:^(VOCNetworkManagerResponse *networkManagerResponse) {

                                            if (completionHandler) {
                                                completionHandler(nil);
                                            }
                                        }];
}
```

and the problem comes right at the beginning when I try to call

> networkManager.startRequest

Xcode autocompletes the method with "onCompletion" instead of onSuccess. And it doesn't recognize "jsonResponse" anyway.

in VOCNetworkManager class there are two methods with the same name (I don't know if this is usual in Objective C):

one calling 'onSucces'

```
-(void) startRequestWithConfiguration: (VOCRequestConfiguration *) configuration onSuccess: (void ( ^ _Nonnull)(NSArray * _Nonnull jsonResponse)) success
                        onFailure: (void (^)(VOCNetworkManagerResponse *networkManagerResponse)) failure {
//NSLog(@"STARTING REQUEST NETWORK MANAGER");
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@%@", configuration.baseUrl, configuration.endPoint];
```

and the second one calls 'onCompletion'

```
-(void) startRequestWithConfiguration: (VOCRequestConfiguration *) configuration onCompletion: (void (^)(NSDictionary *jsonResponse, NSError *error)) completionHandler {

NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@%@", configuration.baseUrl, configuration.endPoint];

[[self getNetworkingManager] POST: url parameters: configuration.parameters progress: nil
                          success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
```

but from my Swift class it looks like if I could only get the second one, so I can't convert the method at all.

It's not the first time I have this kind of problems with completionHandlers tbh

**Header file**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class VOCRequestConfiguration;
@class VOCNetworkManagerResponse;
@class VOCMultipartRequestConfiguration;

@interface VOCNetworkManager : NSObject

+(id _Nullable) sharedManager;

-(void) startRequestWithConfiguration: (VOCRequestConfiguration *_Nullable) configuration onSuccess: (void ( ^ _Nonnull)( NSArray * _Nonnull jsonResponse)) success
                            onFailure: (void (^_Nullable)(VOCNetworkManagerResponse * _Nullable networkManagerResponse)) failure;

-(void) startApplicationJSONContentRequestWithConfiguration: (VOCRequestConfiguration *_Nullable) configuration onSuccess: (void ( ^ _Nonnull)( NSArray * _Nonnull jsonResponse)) success
                            onFailure: (void (^_Nullable)(VOCNetworkManagerResponse * _Nullable networkManagerResponse)) failure;

-(void) startRequestForFile: (VOCMultipartRequestConfiguration *_Nullable) configuration onSuccess: (void (^_Nullable)(NSArray * _Nullable response)) success onFailure: (void (^_Nullable)(void)) failure;

-(void) startRequestWithConfiguration: (VOCRequestConfiguration *_Nullable) configuration onCompletion: (void (^_Nullable)(NSDictionary * _Nullable jsonResponse, NSError * _Nullable error)) completionHandler;

-(void) uploadFile: (VOCMultipartRequestConfiguration *_Nullable) configuration onSuccess: (void (^_Nullable)(NSArray * _Nullable response)) success onFailure: (void (^_Nullable)(void)) failure;

@end
```

Comment: Please format the method.

Comment: sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: The code, format the code so it becomes more readable

Comment: @ManuelLagunaMatias can you please post the .h file

Comment: This seems unusual because header file has the definition. can you clean derived data folder `/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` and restart xcode and see if this works.

Comment: oh I can access to jsonResponse now, thanks!

Comment: @ManuelLagunaMatias I posted an answer please try that once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey it seems that compiler wants to know all the information to make these methods available to swift.

So instead of

```
@class VOCRequestConfiguration;
@class VOCNetworkManagerResponse;
@class VOCMultipartRequestConfiguration;
```

use

```
#import "VOCRequestConfiguration.h"
#import "VOCNetworkManagerResponse.h"
#import "VOCMultipartRequestConfiguration.h"
```